# Calling void methods but deference parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

I call two methods void at the same time, the problem is that the second method I call is not executed, only the first call works fine. The only difference is the parameters

Which calls the method :

```
private void calculateDistributorRabat(InvoiceHeader invoice, Distributor distributor) {
    insertRabatToWallet(distributor.getUser(), invoice.getPurchaseOrder());
    insertRabatToWallet(distributor.getBranchOffice().getUser(), invoice.getPurchaseOrder());
}
```

This is the void method that is being called :

```
private void insertRabatToWallet(User user, PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder) {
    Map<ProductType, Rabat> rabatMap = rabatService.getRabatMapPayPo(user.getUserType());
    Wallet wallet = walletDao.findByUser(user);
    if (wallet == null) {
        wallet = new Wallet();
        wallet.setUser(user);
    }
    for (PurchaseOrderDetail pd : purchaseOrder.getPurchaseOrderDetails()) {
        Rabat rabat = rabatMap.get(pd.getProductType());
        if (rabat == null) {
            continue;
        }
        BigDecimal rabatAmount = rabat.getNominal().multiply(new BigDecimal(pd.getProductQty()));

        wallet.setTotalDebet(wallet.getTotalDebet().add(rabatAmount));
        wallet.setCurrentAmount(wallet.getCurrentAmount().add(rabatAmount));

        WalletTransaction wt = new WalletTransaction();
        wt.setAmount(rabatAmount);
        wt.setDescription("Rabat " + user.getUserType() + " [" + purchaseOrder.getPurchaseOrderNumber()
                + "] (" + pd.getProductType().getCode()
                + "): Rp." + rabat.getNominal().setScale(0).toString()
                + " x " + pd.getProductQty());
        wallet.addWalletTransaction(wt);
        walletDao.save(wallet);

    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that it's a void method shouldn't be relevant. What happens with the second call? Does it throw an exception by any chance? (For example, if `distributor.getBranchOffice()` returns null, you won't get as far as the call because you'll get a `NullPointerException`...)

Comment: How do you know the second method is not called?
And do you see any warning or error logs?

Comment: I have logged in and there are no errors @GreyFairer. More precisely it is not executed, if it is executed, I will definitely get two different values in database.

Comment: Either attach a debugger, or add logging until you can see what's happening.